# How to change id column type already registered in the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm trying to change my Id column type from int to bigInt because the records are too big and I'm getting an error if I try to store more records but I'm not sure if it's safe to just alter the table like this:

```
 alter table the_table
     alter the_column type bigint;
```

I'm using Java Springboot to create the entities and Hibernate for persistence. What's the best way to solve this issue in a safe way since there are very important records inside the DB?

Comment: Is id a primary key or the first node of a compound key or referenced in a foreign key anywhere in your db? Are there any triggers in the table which may push id into another table? Do you have reports or web pages which may need resizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just do this?

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN ID bigint
```

I guess try it in a test environment first but this always works for me

Comment: Do i also have to change the data type in the code or does it not affect anything?

Comment: I think It does not affect anything, but please backup the database(for safety purposes) & then try it on a test environment.

Comment: Test on dev was sucessful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Proper SQL code for MySQL would be:

`ALTER TABLE the_table MODIFY COLUMN the_column BIGINT;`

It will take some time for big tables (as it needs to copy data); if you want to make it without an outage on the table, you can try to use `pt-online-schema-change` command from percona tools (https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/3.0/pt-online-schema-change.html) or if you want to do it more safely (but with an outage on data)

```
RENAME TABLE the_table TO the_table_old
CREATE TABLE the_table LIKE the_table_old
REPLACE INTO the_table select * from the_table_old limit 0,1000
REPLACE INTO the_table select * from the_table_old limit 1000,1000
REPLACE INTO the_table select * from the_table_old limit 2000,1000
DROP TABLE the_table_old
```

But answering your question - It's a safe way to do alter on the table; it just can take some time and that table will be locked to updates/inserts if you just run alter table